# What is the best equation of state for an isothermal compression of high pressure and temperature for steam

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

The best equation of state for isothermal compression of steam at high pressure and temperature

Comment: Hot water is sent to a boiler, heated, and turned into high pressure steam, and that steam is expanded through a cylinder or turbine to do work.  It is very unlikely that anybody in the world has developed a process to compress steam rather than expand it, because such a process would require a lot of input work and would tend to be expensive and impractical.

Comment: Have you considered using the steam tables?

Comment: U still don't get my question. U understand that an idea gas equation which is one equation of state has limitations, they are many equation of state that model the behaviour of real gases like water vapour (steam). I just need one equation of state that is best to model the behaviour of steam at high pressure and temperature under isothermal compression condition. I find it hard to know the best one since they are many

Comment: Please out of experience I need answers because I will be doing alot of mathematical operations on the equation of state u provide. I just don't want  the choosing equation to lost its generality after alot of mathematical operations.